# How to fix #1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xE6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x01...'

Tags: mysql, gis, mysql-8.0

I want to convert a GIS application with postgresql database to mysql 8, i have convert many query to sql query. the app can running but it cant show many spatial function. Like a geom of the place and so on. N I need to input data of the place to mysql 8. So, I have try manual method to input the geom, with lat long in phpmyadmin.

but for the first i execute the query.

```
INSERT INTO `restaurant`(`name`, `address`, `open`, `close`, `price`, `description`, `geom`, `id`) VALUES ('Ajo Paris', 'Jl. S. Parman No.126','' ,'' ,'15000' ,'' , ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100.3481273 -0.9175653)', 4326 ), 'R0001');
```

it has been error,

## 3617 - Latitude 100.348127 is out of range in function st_geomfromtext. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].

I think it has wrong position of lat long, so i reverse it

```
INSERT INTO `restaurant`(`name`, `address`, `open`, `close`, `price`, `description`, `geom`, `id`) VALUES ('Ajo Paris', 'Jl. S. Parman No.126','' ,'' ,'15000' ,'' , ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-0.9175653 100.3481273)', 4326 ), 'R0001');
```

but its still error

## 1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xE6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x01...' for column 'geom' at row 1

does it maybe relate with the collation of column?
The column's collation is utf8_general_ci.

if it isn't relate, What could be the problem? n what should i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to insert `GEOMETRY` type value into a column of type `TEXT` or `CHAR`.

This does not make much sense, even if worked. The Geometry is not stored as the text you typed, it is converted to internal binary representation and should be stored in `GEOMETRY` typed column. Otherwise you would not be able to do much with it.

Define the column as  `geom GEOMETRY SRID 4326`.

Comment: Oh youre right the type of column is longtext. but when i try to change the type to geometry i get the error #1416 cannot get geometry object from data you send to the Geometry field

Comment: When do you get this new error? When running ALTER TABLE, or commands in original question, or something else?

Comment: Yap, When running ALTER TABLE restaurant MODIFY COLUMN geom GEOMETRY

Comment: But that just means some data already there is not valid Geometry field. Fixing it depends on what the data is. Or just replace it with NULL before running MODIFY COLUMN. And please don't forget to upvote / mark as answer :).

Comment: Youre right, haha. I deleted all data and executed. Thanks